# Resolving the "unreachable 'var' after 'return'" problem

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am sharing the codes below.

```
//Calling MODIS LST datasets, Import image collection
var modis = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD11A2');

// A start date is defined and the end date is determined by advancing 1 year from the start date.
var start = ee.Date('2021-03-01');
var end = ee.Date ('2021-03-30');
var dateRange = ee.DateRange(start, start.advance(1, 'month'));

// Filter the LST collection to include only images from time frame and select day time temperature band

var modLSTday = modis.filterDate(dateRange).select('LST_Day_1km');

// Scale to Kelvin and convert to Celsius, set image acquisition time.
var modC = modLSTday.map(function(image) {
  return image
    .multiply(0.02)
    .subtract(273.15)
    .copyProperties(image, ['system:time_start']);
    
    // Chart the time-series
    
var temp_trend = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: modC,
  region: DDN,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.median(),
  scale: 1000,
  xProperty: 'system:time_start'})
  .setOptions({
    lineWidth: 1,
    pointSize: 3,
    trendlines: {0: {
        color: 'CC0000'
      }},
     title: 'LST  Time Series',
     vAxis: {title: 'LST Celsius'}});
print(temp_trend);
});
```

Comment: "Wall of code" questions tend to attract downvotes. Please review the [Tour] to better understand what is expected in a Question here (an introductory paragraph explaining the environment and task is a good start, then you can explain the problem)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/9dd554a271d921b8f335dc8e120293f3

I hope this solves your problem

```
//Calling MODIS LST datasets, Import image collection var modis = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD11A2');

// A start date is defined and the end date is determined by advancing 1 year from the start date. var start = ee.Date('2021-03-01'); var end = ee.Date ('2021-03-30'); var dateRange = ee.DateRange(start, start.advance(1, 'month'));

// Filter the LST collection to include only images from time frame and select day time temperature band
var modis = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD11A1")
var modLSTday = modis.filterDate('2019-01-01', '2020-01-01').select('LST_Day_1km');

// Scale to Kelvin and convert to Celsius, set image acquisition time. var modC = modLSTday.map(function(image) { return image .multiply(0.02) .subtract(273.15) .copyProperties(image, ['system:time_start']);

// Chart the time-series
var temp_trend = ui.Chart.image.series({ 
  imageCollection: modLSTday, 
  region: DDN, 
  reducer: ee.Reducer.median(),
  scale: 1000, xProperty: 'system:time_start'}) .setOptions({ 
                                                     lineWidth: 1, 
                                                     pointSize: 3, 
                                                     trendlines: {0: { color: 'CC0000' }}, 
                                                     title: 'LST Time Series', 
                                                     vAxis: {title: 'LST Celsius'}});
print(temp_trend)
```

Comment: Thankyou sir,  i have now shared my entire codes that requires corrections please help.  Link of the questions: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/414691/dear-exprts-my-codes-requirs-a-lot-of-corrections-and-consist-issues-of-unknow

Comment: This answer comments out a rather integral piece of the original code, essentially bypassing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You get the error because you are attempting to plot the results inside the `map()` function. Nothing after a `return` statement in a function is executed.

```js
//Calling MODIS LST datasets, Import image collection
var modis = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD11A2');

// A start date is defined and the end date is determined by advancing 1 year from the start date.
var start = ee.Date('2021-03-01');
var end = ee.Date ('2021-03-30');
var dateRange = ee.DateRange(start, start.advance(1, 'month'));

// Filter the LST collection to include only images from time frame and select day time temperature band

var modLSTday = modis.filterDate(dateRange).select('LST_Day_1km');

// Scale to Kelvin and convert to Celsius, set image acquisition time.
var modC = modLSTday.map(function(image) {
  return image
    .multiply(0.02)
    .subtract(273.15)
    .copyProperties(image, ['system:time_start']);
});  // close the map function
    
// Chart the time-series
    
var temp_trend = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: modC,
  region: DDN,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.median(),
  scale: 1000,
  xProperty: 'system:time_start'})
  .setOptions({
    lineWidth: 1,
    pointSize: 3,
    trendlines: {0: {
        color: 'CC0000'
      }},
     title: 'LST  Time Series',
     vAxis: {title: 'LST Celsius'}});

print(temp_trend);

// }); is moved before the plotting to correctly close the `map` function
```

[The result](https://code.earthengine.google.com/ba2bef9696b3652ab425384df9e4c118) (which uses an arbitrary `DDN` as one was not supplied)

Comment: Thankyou sir,  i have now shared my entire codes that requires corrections please help.  Link of the questions: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/414691/dear-exprts-my-codes-requirs-a-lot-of-corrections-and-consist-issues-of-unknow

Comment: If the answer solved this particular issue, please accept it as correct